# Random sound generator every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to generate a random sound every 5 seconds and my problem is changing the src in the audio tags from html in javascript(see code) 
I'm getting this error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Can anyone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

```
 (JS) 

 document.getElementById("song-generator").src = "test.mp3";


(html)

<embed
     id="song-generator"
  hidden="true"
  name="test"
  src=""
  loop="true"
  autostart="true"
/>
```

Comment: We might be able to find the problem more easily if you post a minimal, complete, verifiable example: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: Where did you put the js code? before the `embed` tag or after? And did you wrap the code in a callback to wait for the browser to load resource?

Comment: i put the js code  after it and also no, i'm not really sure how to do that I'm a beginner.

Comment: https://codepen.io/cruzgerman216/pen/YdreRL

Comment: All the files are in my local dir. sorry if it looks messy and such but that's all the code...

Comment: https://codepen.io/cruzgerman216/pen/maBXYQ

Comment: i think that is more simplier @per

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `document.getElementById("song-generator")` evaluates to `null` tells me a few possible things:

1. You might have some duplicate ID in your HTML.
2. There's a syntax error somewhere in your HTML.

If those problems are persisting after those checks, then I suspect you're calling `getElementById` prior to the HTML being loaded. To account for this, I'd wrap the JS code in an event listener for the ['load'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event like this:

```js
<!-- Either put your actual JS code here, or link a script -->

<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    //put business logic here
    document.getElementById("song-generator").src = "test.mp3";
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use `window.onload`, which does [the same thing](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp):

```js
<!-- Either put your actual JS code here, or link a script -->

<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    //put business logic here
    document.getElementById("song-generator").src = "test.mp3";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i had my script tags inside the head for some reason and i put them after the html. The error went away but the sound file doesn't play unless i go to the browser console.